# making the default value for a migration based upon a calculation using two other columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm adding a column to a model and I want the new column's default to be the sum of two of the existing columns in that table. Not sure if this is possible. Here's the (invalid) migration I tried:

```
class AddRoundsWithSpeaksToCases < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :cases, :rounds_with_speaks, :integer, default: :wins + :losses
  end
end
```

Is there a way to do this via a migration, or do I have to run `rails console` and update the attributes through there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't want to set the migration up that way because `:wins + :losses` is irrelevant for a new `Case` record. The default should be 0, since by "default" the value of the field will be 0 for new records.

Additionally, you don't have to rely on the console to run the update, you can put it in the migration:

```
class AddRoundsWithSpeaksToCases < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :cases, :rounds_with_speaks, :integer, default: 0
    Case.find_each(batch_size: 200) { |c| c.update_attribute!(:rounds_with_speaks, c.wins + c.losses) }
  end

  def down
    remove_column :cases, :rounds_with_speaks
  end
end
```

Comment: Careful with `Case.all`. That will return an `Array` and eager load __all__ table rows in one go. You should use something like this instead: `Case.find_each(batch_size: 200) { |c| .... }`

Comment: @tompave Definitely a must for large databases. I'll add it to my answer

Answer (score 1):

As a one time migration, to the historical records, you can do it like this:

```
class AddRoundsWithSpeaksToCases < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :cases, :rounds_with_speaks, :integer
    update "UPDATE cases SET rounds_with_speaks = wins+losses"
  end
end
```

This won't affect any future records, you could write something like these as a SQL trigger/procedure..

Comment: I actually don't want it to affect future records, so this is perfect. Thanks!